# How can I replace pictures in Libre Office documents?

Tags: libreoffice, templates

I have a document that I want to use as a template every so often; I will change the pictures and some of the text, but want to keep the general layout.

I have been able to do the *replace picture* thing in MS Word, and from the reading I have done, it looks like it was also done easily in Open Office.

How can we do this in Libre Office?